# Max by group - what factors do my values belong to?

Tags: r, max, subset

I have a dataframe with two groups and values. I have to find `max` value by one group (`group`) and discover, to which values does my `max` correspond to in the second group (`dist`).

```
# example
df<-data.frame(group = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 5),
               val = 1:10,
               dist = rep(c("NR", "b1"), 5))


        > df
       group val dist
1      a   1   NR
2      a   2   b1
3      a   3   NR
4      a   4   b1
5      a   5   NR
6      b   6   b1
7      b   7   NR
8      b   8   b1
9      b   9   NR
10     b  10   b1
```

I can get the max values by group:

```
aggregate(val ~ group, df, max)

  group val
1     a   5
2     b  10
```

or by `tapply`:

```
tapply(df$val, df$group, max)
```

but I need to know, in what "dist" is `max` located.

```
  group val  dist
1     a   5   NR
2     b  10   b1
```

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `slice` the row which have the `max` 'val' for each 'group'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  slice(which.max(val))
```

If there are ties for max value, then do a comparison and `filter` the rows

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(val == max(val))
```

---

Or with `ave` from `base R`

```
df[with(df, val == ave(val, group, FUN= max)),]
#    group val dist
#5      a   5   NR
#10     b  10   b1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df<-data.frame(group = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 5),
               val = 1:10,
               dist = rep(c("NR", "b1"), 5))

df1 <- split(df, df$group)
df2 <- lapply(df1, function(i) i[which(i$val== max(i$val)),] )
df3 <- do.call(rbind, df2)
```